# Rebinding Item Source in List View in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

I have a `ListView` binding employee list. Frame contains one search filter which will rebind list view according to searched element. `ListView` binds well for the first time but when binding again with search element, list view does not get updated.

Here is my code to rebind `ListView`:

```
List<TeamResponse> teamList = new List<TeamResponse>();
 teamList= getTeamResponseList();
 lv_employee.Items.Clear();
 lv_employee.ItemsSource = teamList;
```

**teamList** is the name of response list and **lv_employee** is the name of my list view control.

I am using this in universal windows app.

Comment: Can you add the xaml for that ListView as well? You're talking about bindings here, but you actually set the ItemsSource from code-behind. Are you doing both? Either way, you only have to assign (through binding or from code) the ItemsSource once. Also, you'll want to use an `ObservableCollection<TeamResponse>` instead of a `List`, this way, changes to it will propagate to the ListView.

Comment: Try putting  lv_employee.ItemsSource =null & re-assign item source. Or Use Observable collection binding.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I found the solution.
The main culprit here was clearing the ListView in runtime. Removing following line from code made my code run fine.

```
lv_employee.Items.Clear();
```